# wxBitmap::LoadFile fails in Windows

Tags: wxwidgets

I am trying to load an Image file of type .xpm into the wxBitmap Object using LoadFile method. The following call fails

```
wxBitmap aBitmap;
aBitmap.LoadFile(strIconPath,wxBITMAP_TYPE_XPM);
```

with the error

```
No image handler for type wxBITMAP_TYPE_XPM defined.
```

Whereas, if I load it by including the xpm file and using it as shown below, it works.

```
#include "Icon.xpm"

wxBitmap aBitmap;
aBitmap.CopyFromIcon(wxIcon(Icon_xpm));
```

What is the problem with the first implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to use XPM files then `wxImage::AddHandler(new wxXPMHandler);` should fix it, otherwise `wxInitAllImageHandlers();` is easier for multiple image types. Both of these need to be called before you try to load the file.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `::wxInitAllImageHandlers();` before the LoadFile call or changing the image type specified in the LoadFile call to `wxBITMAP_TYPE_ANY`.